# Gnuplot default palette

Tags: gnuplot, palette

After long time using gnuplot, the default plot palette has changed for me. I would like to change it to the default (red, green...) or at least find where I can use other user-definde palettes without having to define linestyles at the beginning.

This happens both in wxt and pngcairo terms.

Comment: color-blind people won't be happy with this :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color sequence has changed recently (version 5).

To revert to the original color sequence you need to

```
set colorsequence classic
```

Type `help set colorsequence` for more help.